# sql except like query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want search articles with:

```
SELECT *
FROM articles
WHERE `body` LIKE `%src="http://%"
```

But I want except:

```
src="//example.com"
src="//media.example.com"
```

I try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `articles`
WHERE `body` LIKE '%src="http://%' AND
      `body` NOT LIKE '%src="http://example.com%' AND
      `date_show` >= '2018-06-24'
LIMIT 20
```

But I get wrong results. How I can do this correctly?

Comment: What you want to exclude doesn't have "http" in the pattern.

Comment: Can you post up some sample data and your expected outcome

Comment: As a side note, not really related with the Question, having a LIMIT without an ORDER BY, does not make much sense

Comment: I think you want use regex

Comment: Wrong results?  What does that mean exactly?  Define what results you're getting, what you're expecting, and show some sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `body` LIKE '%src="http://%' 
and  `body`  not in (SELECT body
FROM `articles` where `body` NOT LIKE '%src="http://example.com%' )  AND
      `date_show` >= '2018-06-24' LIMIT 20;
```